# Retrieve PromiseResolve data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, promise

I am retrieving tab data from Google Chrome, stored in a Promise object that will be fulfilled with an array. The proper data is currently stored in a Promise object, but I want to only access the array itself.

I have tried wrapping the result in a new Promise and trying to resolve it again, but I keep getting the data in a Promise object.

```
export async function getTabData(){
  let tabs = [];
  await window.chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(data){
    for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
      tabs.push(data[i]);
    };
  });
  return tabs;
}

export async function getPromise() {
  const promise1 = await Promise.resolve(getTabData())
    .then(i => i)
  new Promise(function(res, rej){
    res(promise1);
  })
    .then(function(result){
      return Promise.resolve(promise1);
    })
    .then(function(result){
      console.log(result);
  });
}
```

I expect to get an array of Tabs, but I get a Promise object where that array is stored within the PromiseValue
[image: The Promise object returned]

Answer (score 2):

You can't `await` the tabs query since it isn't returning a promise. So wrap it in a new promise and resolve it in the callback.

Currently the array is being returned empty and populated after you log it

```
export function getTabData() {  
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    window.chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, resolve);
  });
}

export async function doTabsStuff() {
  const tabs = await getTabData();
  // do something with tabs array
}
```

Comment: it works within the function only for now. running a few more tests

Comment: An `async` function always returns a promise

Comment: i get that but then how do i get only the array from the promisevalue?

Comment: Either using `then()` or `await`

Comment: I ran saved the function with a `then()` and then returned the data, but I still only got the Promise object: `const data = doTabsStuff().then(d=>d);`

Comment: Yes... `data` will be promise....you need to work with `d` in the `then()`

Comment: Where you say `// do something with tabs array`, I want to export the data as an array to a React component and then map data. It keeps showing up as a Promise object. What exactly would I do with that data?

Comment: I can only see the data in a print; I want to extract it: ```async getData(){
    var x= await doTabsStuff();
    console.log(x);
  }```

Comment: Ok. I'm not too familiar with async/await and promise. I am only using it because the response type for this API is a Promise array